"Do" in a 1932 text: acronym, or what?
Dorothy L. Sayers, Gaudy Night, XII, p. 285:

March 7 – abusive letter by post to Miss de Vine,' `March 11, do, to Miss Hillyard and Miss Layton (…)

Any idea about that “do” in the second entry? No dictionary search was of any use. An acronym, maybe related to the fact that a letter was delivered by post…?

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/do

I'd guess, from the context, that it's an abbreviation of ditto.

I should have thought of that. Thank you very much!

The question should be reopened, so that @KillingTime's comment can be posted as the answer. While that answer can be found in a dictionary, this can be done only by someone who already realises that do is used here as an abbreviation, and many present-day speakers of English will not realise that.

I believe that do with a comma in the quotation should actually be a full stop -- which being followed by a lower-case to would point to an abbreviation.

As Andrew Leach notes in a comment beneath the posted question, the comma following "do" reported by the poster appears to be incorrect. A snippet view of the relevant text from a 1936 edition of Gaudy Night follows "do" with a period. Here is the relevant passage:

She [the Dean] made a note of the outrage: "The Search by C. P. Snow, pp. 327 to 340 removed and mutilated, May 13th," and passed the information on to Harriet, who incorporated it in her diary of the case, together with such items as: "March 7—abusive letter by post to Miss de Vine," "March 11, do. to Miss Hillyard and Miss Layton," "April 29—Harpy drawing to Miss Flaxman," of which she had now quite a formidable list.

Gaudy Night was originally published in 1935. Several relatively recent editions of the novel that Google Books search results turn up include a comma rather than a period after "do," but I trust the earlier published version here.
The full-length Oxford English Dictionary (1971) has only one entry for "do."—and, consistent with KillingTime's surmise (in another comment beneath the posted question), it involves use of "do." as a short form of ditto:

Do., abbreviation of DITTO. [Earliest cited occurrence:] 1730–6 BAILEY (folio), Do, is frequently us'd by merchants and tradesmen for DITTO.

The sense of the sentence in Dorothy Sayers's novel, therefore, is approximately as follows:

"March 11, abusive letters by post to Miss Hillyard and Miss Layton."

